# calling a function declared in header file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have x.h file and y.h file, z.c file. z.c includes y.h and y.h includes x.h.
I have a function that need to be declared in x.h and defined in z.c, because it needs to use some other functions in y.h.

I tried like this

```
// x.h
int foo();

// y.h
#include "x.h"

// z.c
#include"y.h"
int foo() {
   blah;
   blah;
   return 1;
}
```

this is all in one project lets say in x_y.dll and it compiled well and i have x_y.dll, x_y.lib

Now in other project a_b
in one of the a.c file I am trying to include x.h and call foo();
compiles well, but I am having the linker error lnk2019 and lnk1120 unresolved external symbols

I am working on VS2008, I have the path set to the folder where x_y.lib located.

Comment: My mistake errors were lnk2019 and lnk1120

Comment: Have you set the library dependencies in your Project Settings?

Comment: Yes I did, let me correct if I am wrong, right click on project->proporties->General->additional library Directories: here I have the path in place to the lib files

Comment: and under input additional dependencies I have the lib file name in place

Comment: I'm no MSVC expert, but don't the functions have to include a `__declspec(dllexport)` declaration to be exported from the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a macro like so:

```
#ifndef DLL_IFACE
#ifdef DLL_IFACE_EXPORT
#define DLL_IFACE _declspec( dllexport )
#else  // !DLL_IFACE_EXPORT
#define DLL_IFACE _declspec( dllimport )
#endif // !DLL_IFACE_EXPORT
#endif // !DLL_IFACE
```

And put this in some header included by everyone. Then in x.h:

```
DLL_IFACE int foo();
```

then in z.c, start that file off with:

```
#define DLL_IFACE_EXPORT
```

This will cause the function to be declared "_declspec( dllexport )" when you build the dll that defines the function. And will cause the function to be declared "_declspec( dllimport )" in other dlls.

The dllexport tells the compiler that the given function should be part of a dll's public interface. It put the function in the dll's dynamic symbol table. dllimport tells the compiler that the function will be imported through dynamic linking later.

Comment: Does function definition needs to include DLL_IFACE I mean
DLL_IFACE int foo() {
blah;
blah;
return 1;
}